# Custom Popup Editor not open when grid is empty

Tags: kendo-ui

I have made the html template and i am using that template in popup editor.If i have atleast one record in grid then it will perfectly but if there is no data in grid then if click on add button then custom popup editor will not open.There is no error given but popup editor not open.So anybody know solution of this problem?Thanks in advance.
**EDIT**
this is the template i have used.

```
<script id="teamEditorTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <form  method="POST">
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div >
                        Area Prefix:                
                    </div></td>
                <td><div>
                        <input name="area_prefix" class="k-input k-textbox" style="text-align: left" id="area_prefix" required  validationMessage="Please Enter Area Prefix"/>                        
                    </div></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><div >
                        Area Name:                
                    </div></td>
                <td><div>
                        <input name="area_name" class="k-input k-textbox" style="text-align: left" id="area_name" required  validationMessage="Please Enter Area Name"/>                        
                    </div></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><div >
                        Source:                
                    </div></td>
                <td><div>
                        <input name="source" style="text-align: left" id="source" required  validationMessage="Please Select Source"/>                        
                    </div></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><div >
                        Country Name:                
                    </div></td>
                <td><div>
                        <input name="vox_country_id" style="text-align: left" id="vox_country_id" required  validationMessage="Please Select Country"/>                        
                    </div></td>
            </tr>

   </table>
    </form>    
</script>
```

The kendo ui code is here

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
           pageSize: 10,
             serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            sortable:true,
                pageable: { 
                            refresh: true,
                             pageSizes:[10,20,50,100]
                        },
            height: 400,
            toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add New Area" }],
            columns: [
                { field:"area_prefix", title: "Area Prefix",width:70 },
                { field: "area_name", title:"Area Name",width:90},
                { field: "source", title:"Source",width:70, template: '#= getsourceName(source) #'},
                 { field: "vox_country_id", width:70,template: '#= getCountryName(vox_country_id) #'},
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Action",width:53}],
            editable: {
                mode: "popup",            
                template: $("#teamEditorTemplate").html(),
                update: true,  
                add:true,
                destroy: true,

                confirmation: "Are you sure you want to remove ?"
            },
            edit: function(e) {
                if(!e.model.id){
                    $(e.container).parent().find('.k-window-title').html("Add Area Details");
                    $(e.container).parent().find('.k-grid-update').html("Save");
                }
             }
        });
```

Comment: Very difficult to help without any code sample at all. Can you provide a jsFiddle or code example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You should provide some exact code since I've tried creating an empty grid and it open popup editor. How does the template look like? How do you use it?

Comment: Please check the above edited question.I have put the code of template and kendo grid.

Comment: Can you please tell me that if pass that in controller and if no any data in database so have you pass blank array if no data ?

Comment: but when wwe click on add button then at that time we don't need any data from database.After adding record in database we need data from database.So on create is it required to pass blank array?

Comment: I have pass the blank array as $arr[]=array(); But still it will no open the popup editor on add button click.

Answer (score 0):

There is one missing information in your question: how did you define the datasource and what are `getsourceName` and `getCountryName`.

Trying to reproduce your problem, what I wrote is the `DataSource` as follow:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data  : [],
    schema: {
        model: {
            id            : "id",
            fields        : {
                area_prefix   : { type: "string" },
                area_name     : { type: "string" },
                source        : { type: "string" },
                vox_country_id: { type: "string" }
            },
            getsourceName : function (d) {
                d = d || "hello";
                return d;
            },
            getCountryName: function (d) {
                d = d || "bye";
                return d;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Where `getsourceName` returns  either `d` (current value) if it is defined and not `null` or `hello`. Similar for `getCountryName`.

When you add a record, there is no previous value and it is likely that it throws some error failing to open the popup window.

But if conveniently check for null then it should work fine.

See the examples that I put together with your code here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/wcZ3L/